# Создание прогресс - графика SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animation

Я работаю над прогресс - графиком SVG, который будет отображать индикатор здоровья в игре, пока он выглядит так: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ds9hpuv)

Идея состоит в том, чтобы иметь отзывчивую полосу, которая уменьшается / увеличивается в длину в зависимости от здоровья персонажа.

Прямо сейчас я не могу понять, как уменьшить этот путь по длине, при постоянном сохранении  скругленного края на правой стороне.

В идеале я хотел бы, чтобы его высота также реагировала на рост здоровья персонажа.

```html
<svg width="428" height="35">

<path d="M0 0h414.333785C423.444595 9.346449 428 15.179782 428 17.5c0 2.320218-4.555405 8.153551-13.666215 17.5H0V0z" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Making svg path with rounded edge responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57608398/7394871) от участника  [@Ilja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/911930/ilja).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57608398/7394871

Comment: Обратите внимание на этот топик по ряду причин: Использован инструмент для [перевода параметров патча из абсолютных величин в относительные](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv).  Это позволяет изменяя всего лишь один параметр в патче легко реализовать анимацию.

Answer (score 1):

Я изменил путь, изменив каждую команду на строчные (используя этот инструмент: [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute](https://codepen.io/leaverou/pen/RmwzKv),   но я оставил последнюю команду `H` в верхнем регистре, так как `H0` возвращается к `x = "0"`

Затем я заменяю первую команду `h` на переменную `healthIndicator`

Я предполагаю, что наконечник стрелки имеет только эстетическую функцию.

```js
itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let healthIndicator = itr.value;
  let d = `M0,0 h${healthIndicator}c9.111,9.346,13.666,15.18,13.666,17.5c0,2.320218,-4.555405,8.153551,-13.666215,17.5H0v-35z`;
  thePath.setAttributeNS(null,"d", d);
  
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 550 35" >

<path id="thePath" d="M0,0
                      h414
                      c9.111,9.346,13.666,15.18,13.666,17.5
                      c0,2.320218,-4.555405,8.153551,-13.666215,17.5
                      H0z" fill="red"/>

</svg>

<input type="range" id="itr" value="414" min="0" max="500" />
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Making svg path with rounded edge responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57610006/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>